# Full integration of zipping feature in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, zip

On a daily basis, I get reports, containing hyperlinks to zipfiles on a server, who contain crash dump files.

The mentioned hyperlinks look as follows:

```
\\servername\Base_Directory\Sub_Directory\FileName.zip
```

When I click on such a hyperlink, Windows explorer is started and shows me the content of that zipfile:

```
Windows explorer address bar:
  \\servername\Base_Directory\Sub_Directory\FileName.zip
Windows explorer content:
  crash_dumpfile.DMP
  More_information.txt
```

When I click on "crash_dumpfile.DMP", that dumpfile gets opened in Visual Studio, but the name of the file changes into something like:

```
C:\Users\DominiqueDS\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_FileName.zip\crash_dumpfile.DMP
```

As I'm opening lots of such dumpfiles simultaneously, I can't follow which dumpfile corresponds with which zipfile anymore, so I'd like the dumpfile (in Visual Studio) to be something like:

```
\\servername\Base_Directory\Sub_Directory\FileName.zip\crash_dumpfile.DMP
```

(as it is in Windows explorer)

I believe this means that zipping needs to be more "integrated" into Windows-10 as it currently is.

Does anybody know how to complete the zipping integration in Windows-10?

Comment: There's no more integration than it already has. You may want to extract the files instead. Or install some better software for the purpose.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: do you know any software which can achieve that?